# Select GStreamer Element Based on Source Capabilities

Tags: selector, gstreamer, pipeline, skip

Using gst-launch is there any way to select a GStreamer Element based on the capabilities determined by a source element? For example, if I have a network source element which could download an MP3, M4A, or WAV file, can I select which element to pipe the data to based on the file type received? The file type is not actually known until after the network source element is loaded. See the linked image below for the pipeline I have in mind. Any ideas?

[image: GStreamer Element Selector]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use decodebin2 or uridecodebin element. These elements contain autodetct capabilities.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-uridecodebin.html

Comment: Not 100% sure yet, but I think that decodebin is exactly what I'm looking for. My problem now though is that I have a custom type I want decodebin to be able to detect, but the type find functionality isn't working like I would expect. I created another question, see the following link. Any ideas what the problem is? [Type Find Function Not Called in GStreamer Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652668/type-find-function-not-called-in-gstreamer-plugin)

Comment: Never got around to actually trying what I wanted, but I'm guessing that this element, and possibly along with the capsfilter element, would accomplish exactly what I wanted. Thanks!